# Devise - creating users only by admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm creating an app where I need only admins to create new users:

## routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
resources :users
root 'dashboard#index'
```

## users_controller.rb

```
# GET /users/1/edit
#def edit
#  
#end

# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create

  build_resource(sign_up_params)


  respond_to do |format|
    if resource.save

      format.html { redirect_to user_path(resource), notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: user }
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

end
```

When I open http://localhost:3000/users/new

```
I got this error:

AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /users/new
Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/new".
This may happen for two reasons:

1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
  end

2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
   If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

   @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

**What is wrong there? Thank you a lot!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're confusing `Devise` functionality with that of your app:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users #-> nothing to do with devise
```

When you *create* a user, you're using the `devise` `build_resource` helper. Problem being that this will require devise functionality, which is not going to happen for `users_controller`.

To use `sign_up_params` or `build_resource`, you'll have to scope your routes to a `devise` controller (so all the available session data is there)...

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :user, skip: [:registrations]
devise_scope :user do
   resources :users, path: "", only: [:new, :create], controller: "registrations" #-> url.com/users/new
end
```

This way, you'll be able to override the standard `Devise::RegistrationsController` with your own code:

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   before_action :check_admin

   def create
      build_resource(sign_up_params)
      ...
   end

   private

   def check_admin
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
   end
end
```

--

What I would recommend is either removing the `Devise` functionality from your `users` controller, or overriding the `registrations` controller so that only an admin can create a user (which it seems you're trying to do already).